# Why do fat people and thin people get hungry at the same time?

Tags: human-physiology

Say a fat person and a thin person take breakfast at the same time. Around lunchtime, they'll both be hungry. Why? After all, the fat person theoretically has lots of body fat the body can consume instead, so the fat person does not have to feel hungry.

Comment: Consider that part of it is simply social conditioning.  People in western cultures are generally trained to expect meals at certain times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure your statement is true, fat and thin people may not always get hungry at the same time. You cannot simply compare these two categories as they contain subcategories including people "feeling hungry" because of disorders related to their mental health, physiology, diseases,...

The term you are looking for is "appetite regulation" and reading the wikipedia page will give you an overview of this subject and why your question is too broad to be answered. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appetite#Regulation

Comment: I accepted your answer because it tells me that my question is poorly formed: instead of asking "which body needs energy", I should be asking "what governs appetite".